# How to change div style via tampermonkey on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I use a webpage with the following div which shows up after click a specific element on page:

`<div class="ui page modals dimmer transition visible active" style="display: flex !important;">`

I need to change this element to display none via greasemonkey/tampermonkey...
`<div class="ui page modals dimmer transition visible active" style="display: none !important;">`

Best way would be to add a button with the following code. Clicking the button would cycle the previous div between **display none** and **display flex** values. I am a complete noob in greasemonkey and JS, could you help?

```
(function() {
    //'use strict';

    // create button
    var btn = document.createElement( 'input' );
    with( btn ) {
        setAttribute( 'onclick', 'alert( "you clicked me!" )' );
        setAttribute( 'value', 'click me!' );
        setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );
    }

// append at end
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( btn );


})();
```

EDIT:
I tried also this code but without success:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://dr.sestraemmy.cz/
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    //'use strict';

    // create button
    var btn = document.createElement( 'input' );
    with( btn ) {
        setAttribute( 'onclick', 'alert( "you clicked me!" )' );
        setAttribute( 'value', 'click me!' );
        setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );
    }

// append at end
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( btn );
document.getElementsByClassName("ui page modals dimmer transition visible active")[0].style.display="none !important";


})();
```

Comment: I also tried the following code but with no success:

Answer (score 0):

I tried on this page with something like that :

```
(function() {
    //'use strict';
    // create button
    let btn = document.createElement( 'input' );
    btn.addEventListener('click', toggle );
    btn.setAttribute( 'value', 'click me!' );
    btn.setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );

    // append at end
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( btn );
})();

var state = true;

function toggle(){
    let el = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-js.s-code-block")[0];
    if(state) {
        el.style.display = "none";
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = "block";
        state = true;
    }
}
```

It works and will toggle the display of the first js block of code on this page.

Also, if you want to access a dom element you will need to wait for the page to load before trying to get it or it will be undefined. With the load event for example :

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
    let el = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-js.s-code-block")[0];
    console.log(el);
}
```